# Why is the "back" key acting like it is pressed twice?

Tags: unity

I want to show toast message when the user presses the back button.
I am handling button using this code, which is in my `Update` function:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) {
  print ("UPUP");       
  ToastHelper.ShowToast ("Back", false);
  //Application.Quit();
}
```

`ToastHelper` is plugin here.

The issue is that the toast message shows up twice, so it seems like the back key is acting like it was pressed twice. I only want it to execute once.

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling that toast it somewhere else? If you're on visual-studio, can you right-click the ShowToast method and search for uses, to confirm this?

Comment: Yes i am sure, I call it only from that place. 

print statement execute two times that means Back call two times

Comment: @RupalPatel the sparse codesample you post seems to be using key-polling. Are you sure that you don't just keep the back key pressed long enough for your key-handler to poll twice?

Comment: Yes i am sure, i just press Escape key and release as normal not long in pc still it shows two times, And I tested in mobile device, i press single back but it executes two times.

Comment: Is  there any alternative way? Can we do it by making plugin for android?

Comment: Do you maybe have that script on two different game objects?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Unity engine already handles the limit. `GetKeyUp` and `GetKeyDown` will only return `true` in the frame where that state is achieved, they not trigger `true` again until the key is in the opposite state for at least one frame, and then comes back to the triggering state. --- Only `GetKey` will consistently return `true` or `false` for the key being down or up, respectively.

Comment: @Philipp "Do you maybe have that script on two different game objects?" - I think that's the only possible remaining cause, short of a bug in the plugin. +1

Comment: @Philipp & XenoRo yes you are right, that was the cause, script was attached to two gameobject. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

Problem gets solved. Its due to same script attached to two gameobject.

Comment: Minus for what?